# I tried to save json data into a variable, but it gives me KeyError

Tags: python, json, response

I tried to save JSON data into a variable, but it gives me KeyError in Python. There is my code:

```
import json
import requests

r = requests.get("https://api.followrel.ga/api.php?id=1")

# some JSON:
x =  r.text

# parse x:
y = json.loads(x)

print(y["name"])
```

The error that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(y["name"])
KeyError: 'name'
```

And finally the request text:

> {"status":"true","message":"Customer Details","customers":{"id":"1","username":"petyadev","email":"petya200g@gmail.com","name":"Peter Till","bio":"Hell\u00f3. Petya vagyok, a Followrel app k\u00e9sz\u00edt\u0151je.","job":"Followrel","website":"https://www.followrel.ga","coin":"500"}}

I will be very happy if someone can help me

Comment: Can you provide *all* pertinent debugging information, specifically the full stack trace of the error you’re seeing, in accordance with [ask]?

Comment: Alright! I will post it into the question

Comment: You can also just do `y = r.json()`

Comment: The key `name` does not exist at the root level of the JSON Object structure currently present at the URL you’ve referenced in your code. Perhaps you meant to access it within its `customers` parent? Can you elaborate on the line of logic you followed that led you to conclude otherwise?

Comment: @Sayse It still doesn't works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

name does not exist in the y dict its nested inside the customers dict
try:

`print(y["customers"]["name"])`

Comment: Oh thank you! It now works fine